Django q in python anywhere ignores every functionality inside of it but finished without issue just in sync: True - mode
I have a extremely strange behaviour with my django q taks.
When i start running a task, all the actions inside the function that is wropped with the async_task - wrapper will be ignored BUT just when set "sync": False / default. If i set sync: True everything works perfectly (but sync).
I also ahve prepared a gist file here shows the simplified workflow: https://gist.github.com/wired87/5e64fc79d3aa84cdad87ef7803f508ce
But i think the behaviour must come form somewhere else.

play around with dj q fields
checked all tasks djangos admin terminal -> the task is alltimes successfull



Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
